# How to install onlyoffice document server on raspberry pi?

Tags: web-server, lighttpd, docker, repository, nextcloud

I have been trying to install the only office document server for 4 days now. I have tried using the docker method. Everything appear to go right with the docker method, but when I go to http://localhost then only the default apache 2 page is there. Or if I make the apache 2 disabled then enable lighttpd or nginx then same outcome but just different home pages.  I also tried using no-ip for a domain use of server access and I tried http://xxx.x.x.x I also tried sudo bash then apt-get install onlyoffice-document-server method which returned repositories not found error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a futile endeavour. The [System requirements](https://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/server/linux/document/linux-installation.aspx#SystemRequirements) for Document Server include:

- CPU: dual core 2 GHz or better → *while Raspberry Pi 2 & 3 have quad-core processors, they're ~ 1 GHz ARM quad core. Server spec software usually assumes Intel power per core*
- RAM: 2 GB or more → *the most RAM that a Raspberry Pi supports is 1 GB*
- OS: 64-bit Debian, Ubuntu or other compatible distribution → *almost all Raspbian OSs are 32-bit*

No model of Raspberry Pi can meet these requirements.

Comment: What part can't raspberry pi meat?

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: I see thank you guess this is a waste of time and thank you for saving my time

Comment: Do you mind up voteing my post? So I can comment anywhere soon?

Answer (score 0):

Now Raspberry Pi 4 is quad core, 1.5Ghz, up to 8 Go RAM.

This seems to be possible now, following these guidelines :

https://help.nextcloud.com/t/tutorial-installing-onlyoffice-server-on-raspberry-pi-4-ubuntu-server-20-10/100739

It is not trivial though, for experienced users I guess.